# Segmentation fault with Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, segmentation-fault, tk-toolkit

So, I have this function that is supposed to let the user select several image files to include in a document. For some reason, this function crashes every time I run it within my larger program on Mac OSX 10.11.6 and I get a segmentation fault error, specifically segmentation fault 11. Yet, when I run the function on its own, it works just fine. What's going on here?

```
import sys
import logging
from time import strftime
import Tkinter as Tk
import tkFileDialog

def get_filepaths(title=None):
    """
    Gets an unlimited number of filepaths until the user clicks 'Cancel'.
    :param title: The title of the window dialog.
    :return: list of filepaths
    """
    if title is None:
        title = "Select an image to add to the report. Click Done to load " \
                "the file. When you're finished, click Cancel to continue."

    logging.debug("Inputting filepaths...")
    types = (("all files", "*.*"), ("images", "*.jpg *.jpeg *.png *.tiff "
                                              "*.tif *.gif *.bmp *.psd"))
    root = Tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    paths = []
    while True:
        path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(title=title, filetypes=types)
        if len(path) == 0:
            break
        paths.append(path)
    return paths
```

Comment: Are you creating multiple instances of `Tk.Tk`? A tkinter program should have exactly _one_ instance of the `Tk` class.

Comment: @Rawing No, the Tk.Tk you see in the snippet is the only place it appears in the entire program.

Comment: have you seen [python's warnings about tk/tcl on osx](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/)?

Comment: @Novel Yes, I installed a new version of ActiveTCL for use with my virtualenv. When I do `tclsh` followed by `info patchlevel` on the command line, it says I have version 8.6.6.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue on debian Jessie armhf on an orange pi and again on Ubuntu focal armhf on a tritium board. (allwinner H3 cpu,  clone of orange pi). The problem still exists in 2021. There is no problem on Opensuse leap 42.1, X86_64

I found this comment about a simple kludge fix to the Tix library file Utils.tcl and this solved the problem in my code. It bypasses the tixBusy function.

bugs.archlinux.org/task/33607

Comment: Can you post the solutions you've tried so far?